# Amazon SES and Sendy.co issue - only in GMail messages received in spam, orhers in Inbox

Tags: amazon-ses, sendy

we are trying to do mass e-mail sending via Amazon SES and we face issues. Hotmail and Yahoo receive in Inbox. Gmail receives in SPAM. We do everything we need:

- non-blacklisted dedicated IP address from SmarterASP.NET (the hosting)
- non-blacklisted domain: gmatpreptutor.co.uk prepared
- non-spammy content checked with the newsletter we prepared and with
  empty message as well - same situation, received in spam in gmail,
  others - Inbox.
- here are the headers:
  https://gyazo.com/1f5cfc2f0b5041115d8dd1f85483d635
- here is the other data in the message source:
  https://gyazo.com/9cd7c6e4c50cb031625feb0a6201da04  we send from
  Sendy
- we host Sendy on SmarterASP.NET (windows hosting, without ANY hosting
  issues)
- Is there something that we need to do more?
- Is SmarterASP.NET problematic for mass e-mail sending with Sendy,
  using Amazon SES as SMTP, and why?
- Is the domain in anyway problematic, from your point of view, and
  why?
- Is maybe dedicated IP address we purchased from SmarterASP.NET
  problematic, from your point of view, and why?
- Is Windows hosting problematic, from your point of view, and why?
- What else?
- Can Amazon team do any intervention so that this will not be issue
  anymore?

Please, be as specific as you can, so that we can consider the best solution.

Thank you,

Ivan

Comment: The SmarterASP.NET / Windows stuff largely has nothing to do with it. If you're sending from a domain name that hasn't previously been sending large volumes, you'll initially get a lot of spam flags. Reputation takes time to build.

Comment: Thank you @ceejayoz, but this case with a new domain and clear dedicated IP address has nothing to do with spam reception.

Comment: Sure it does. A new domain has no reputation, which means it doesn't have a *good* reputation. That means major providers like Gmail will look skeptically on a sudden large volume from a domain they've never seen email from before.

Comment: Additionally, the IP of your hosting provider has little to do with things (unless it previously was hosting malware/spammy sites). Your email comes from SES, so it's SES's IPs that matter for that bit.

Comment: See ["How to send emails and avoid them being classified as spam?"](https://serverfault.com/questions/48428/how-to-send-emails-and-avoid-them-being-classified-as-spam) over on ServerFault for further info/details.